# Logic behind rule of product solution for a question

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Im working through a book of Discrete and combinatorial mathematics and there is one question that I answered correct, however the solution in the book is very different (and it seems far more efficient than mine) but i simply cannot understand it.

A burger joint advertises that customer can have his burger with or without any of the following: catsup, mustard, mayonnaise, lettuce, tomato, onion, pickle, cheese or mushrooms. How many different burgers can you order?

My solution:
First of all the order of the toppings here are irrelevant. Its very long winded.

```
You can have 0 toppings in 1 way.
You can have 1 topping in 9nCr1 ways
You can have 2 toppings in 9nC2ways
...
You can have 9 toppings in 9nCr9 ways.
Total 512
```

The books solution:

```
"By the rule of product there are 2^9 ways"
```

Im pretty new to this, in my computer science course we don't delve too deep into discrete mathematics and number theory. I struggle with the reasoning behind solutions, so can i ask you to explain each step.
Thank you for all the help,
Rainy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two choices, "have it" or "don't have it" for the nine condiments. Hence, you have two choices nine times, so the number of possible burgers is
$$\underbrace{2 \times 2 \times \cdots \times 2}_{\text{$9$ times}} = 2^9.$$
In fact, your solution is correct also since
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} = \binom{n}{0} + \binom{n}{1} + \cdots + \binom{n}{n} = 2^n,$$
by the binomial theorem!

Comment: Oh i see, wow that is so obvious when you say it. Ive only done binomial in A level, though i think that is the next chapter in the book. Thank you for your answer. Il vote you up when i have enough rep.